# Bitstring collectable throws error on Elixir 1.6.0

Tags: elixir

For some reason this code

```
for i <- 7..0, into: <<>>, do: if i in [0, 1], do: <<1::1>>, else: <<0::1>>
```

fails on Elixir 1.6.0 but not on 1.5.3

**1.6.0**

```
iex(1)> for i <- 7..0, into: <<>>, do: if i in [0, 1], do: <<1::1>>, else: <<0::1>>
** (ArgumentError) argument error
   :erlang.iolist_to_binary([[[[[[[["" | <<0::size(1)>>] | <<0::size(1)>>] | <<0::size(1)>>] | <<0::size(1)>>] | <<0::size(1)>>] | <<0::size(1)>>] | <<1::size(1)>>] | <<1::size(1)>>])
```

**1.5.3**

```
iex(1)> for i <- 7..0, into: <<>>, do: if i in [0, 1], do: <<1::1>>, else: <<0::1>>
<<3>>
```

I've looked around the changelog and haven't seen any changes related to this. I've looked around the codebase some but didn't really see anything stick out.

(update)

Created an issue https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/7234. I'll keep a look out on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in version [1.6.1](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.6/CHANGELOG.md#elixir-1) of elixir.